# How to populate RecyclerView using Java with data that meets condition? For Instance on populate with male candidates

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My RecyclerView is currently populating with all data available on my firebase database but I only want it to populate male candidates for instance. How do I go about doing so?

[image: Image of how it is currently displaying]

This is what I Have on my ListViewActivity

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<EmployerInfo> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EmployerInfo");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    EmployerInfo employerInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(EmployerInfo.class);
                    list.add(employerInfo);
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is myAdapeter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<EmployerInfo> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EmployerInfo> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
       return  new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        EmployerInfo employerInfo = list.get(position);
        holder.firstName.setText(employerInfo.getName());
        holder.lastName.setText(employerInfo.getSurname());
        holder.gender.setText(employerInfo.getGender());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public  static  class  MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView firstName, lastName, gender;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            firstName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstName);
            lastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLastName);
            gender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGender);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using if statement on the listViewActivity but it is return a blank page. I want it to only display data of male candidates

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EmployeeProfile");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    EmployerInfo employerInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(EmployerInfo.class);

                    if(employerInfo.getGender() == "Male"){
                        list.add(employerInfo);
                    }
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Try to avoid using notifyDatasetChanged().  This can be costly, as it is more of a shotgun approach.  Since you are inserting an item at the end of the list each time, use notifyItemInserted(int position) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is no issue with the misspellings, then I think you can use the `equals` method to check the gender string. For example, `employerInfo.getGender().equals("Male")`

Comment: Thanks Alot. Asa simple as that was I would have never thought of tryng that. It helped. It works fine now